# Selenium java - Unable to click on the tabs anchor view

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tabs, click, href

I am unable to click and open a view. Please help.

My screen contains multiple views of same `class="ui-tabs-anchor"` and `href="#s_vctrl_div_tabScreen_noop"` but different text.

The code is as below:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active siebui-active-navtab" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="s_vctrl_div_tabScreen_noop" aria-labelledby="ui-id-434" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Deal Selected">
<a id="ui-id-434" class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#s_vctrl_div_tabScreen_noop" data-tabindex="tabScreen6" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Deal</a>
</li>
```

When the screen opens, by default one view called "Line Items" is selected, but I want to click on a different view called "Deal". I am able to locate the view name like below by using firepath:
[image]

I wrote my code as below:

```
String string1000 = "//*[contains(.//a,'Deal')]";
WebDriverWait wait90 = new WebDriverWait(driver1,60);
wait90.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(string1000))).click();
```

But when it executes, it tries to click on the view, so we see in the screenshot that the view is highlighted (becomes black), BUT it seems IT is NOT CLICKED and so the view is not opened.
[image]

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the parent `li` tag? Also can you try the xpath: `"//a[contains(text(),'Deal')]"` and let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried with the li tag but it behaves just the same. It is not clicked.

Comment: Donno why but the xpath: "//a[contains(text(),'Deal')]" does not locate the element when using the firepath...it does not work also

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
WebElement string1000 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.//a,'Deal')]"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", string1000 );
```

Or

```
Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
builder.moveToElement(string1000).click();
Action build=builder.build();
build.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on a different view called `"Deal"` you can use the following line of code :

```
WebDriverWait wait_4_link = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait_4_link.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Deal"))).click();
```